# How to get a UserControl inside a TabItem?

Tags: c#, wpf

XAML Code:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Margin="-3,-3,-3,-3" Background="Transparent" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
        <TabItem Header="Corn">
            <Grid x:Name="sdfsfd"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem" >
            <local:CornTab x:Name="cornTab"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

CS Code:

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        TabItem ti = ((TabControl)sender).SelectedItem as TabItem;
        Console.WriteLine(ti.Header);

        getChildrenOf(ti, 1);
    }

    private void getChildrenOf(DependencyObject dep, int indents) {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dep); i++) {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dep, i);
            Console.WriteLine($"{new String('\t', indents)}{i}: {child.GetType()}");

            getChildrenOf(child, indents + 1);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to retrieve `<local:CornTab x:Name="cornTab"/>` when I click the `TabItem` but no matter what I do, it won't seem to come out in `VisualTreeHelper` and the printouts are the same with the only difference being the `TabItem.Header`.

```
TabItem
0: System.Windows.Controls.Border
    0: System.Windows.Controls.Grid
        0: MahApps.Metro.Controls.ContentControlEx
            0: System.Windows.Controls.Grid
                0: System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter
                    0: System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
        1: MahApps.Metro.Controls.Underline
            0: System.Windows.Controls.Border
                0: MahApps.Metro.Controls.ClipBorder
                    0: System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter
Corn
    0: System.Windows.Controls.Border
        0: System.Windows.Controls.Grid
            0: MahApps.Metro.Controls.ContentControlEx
                0: System.Windows.Controls.Grid
                    0: System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter
                        0: System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
            1: MahApps.Metro.Controls.Underline
                0: System.Windows.Controls.Border
                    0: MahApps.Metro.Controls.ClipBorder
                        0: System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter
```

Perhaps I need to traverse the control tree differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to traverse the visual tree.

[`TabItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabitem?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a [`ContentControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2) and `ContentControl` sets the `ContentPropertyAttribute` as "Content"

[`System.Windows.Markup.ContentPropertyAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Indicates which property of a type is the XAML content property. A XAML processor uses this information when processing XAML child elements of XAML representations of the attributed type.

Therefore you can simply change your method to this

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    TabItem ti = ((TabControl)sender).SelectedItem as TabItem;
    var content = ti.Content;
    if(content is CornTab cornTab)
    {
        //Do with 'cornTab' whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nosale, I tried your solution as you said but I can't seem to be able to cast it as my class (`CornTab`), it only registers as a grid.

Comment: @LorenzoAng Keep in mind that your first tab contains a `Grid` therefore you need some conditional check (I updated my answer). If `ti.Content` still returns a `Grid` after selecting `<TabItem Header="TabItem" >` there must be some other issue.

Comment: Whoops, you're right! It wasn't the `TabItem` but I forgot I had previously wrapped `cornTab` within a `Grid` as I was experimenting on other solutions with a `VisualTree`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @LorenzoAng When you want to wrap your `cornTab` again in a Grid you can traverse the logical tree using [`LogicalTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.logicaltreehelper?view=netframework-4.7.2). Read also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/trees-in-wpf) to understand the difference between logical and visual tree.

Comment: It's alright, I was just experimenting trying to find a fix, I don't need it wrapped in a grid. Thanks though!